# Slide text over image on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a CSS3 hover effect to some images so that when someone hovers over an image some text will slide up on a white background. I have tried a few guides but I think they're clashing with other code I have (as I also overlay text and a 'new' sign in the corner.

Here's my code so you can see (inline styles included)

```html
<img src="http://stuartgreen.me.uk/pontins/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/penguin-test.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: -11px; right: -11px;">
  <img src="http://stuartgreen.me.uk/pontins/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/new-posts.png">
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 50%; transform: translate(0, -50%); text-align: center;">
  <p style="display: inline-block; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35); font-family: 'Amatic SC'; color: #FFF; text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #3a3c3d; margin: 0; padding: 10px; font-size: 38px; line-height: 38px;">
    Brean Sands
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: would you consider using javascript for that?

Comment: yeah, if it would work I would give it a try for sure.

Comment: It will work, so give it a try.

Comment: Sure, can you point me in the direction to a tutorial for something like that? I'm not familiar with writing Javascript.

Comment: where did you catch hover in CSS

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/slideup/ if you want slide up animation. onmouseover could be what you look for

Comment: I've removed it now because it didn't work. However, I created another div under the second div and that was my hover div in which I added the CSS;

  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  -o-transition: top 0.3s 0s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s 0s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s 0s ease-in-out;
  transition: top 0.3s 0s ease-in-out;

Comment: Thanks Ken, I'll have a look now as thats exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help.

```css
.img {
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid #f00;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.img:hover .overlay,
.overlay:hover {
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}
.img > img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300/eee" />
  <div class="overlay">Hello!</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400/eee" />
  <div class="overlay">Bye!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against using JavaScript for this unless necessary, as if I'm reading your question correctly, it can be done in CSS. Here is an example - I would recommend refactoring all your inline styles out into a style tag, otherwise refactor the new styles into your existing inline styles if you need all your styles to be inline.

```css
#container:hover #name {
  transform: translate(0, 0) !important;
}

#container #name {
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
  transform: translate(0, 100%) !important;
}

#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#name {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<img src="http://stuartgreen.me.uk/pontins/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/penguin-test.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
<div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: -11px; right: -11px;">
  <img src="http://stuartgreen.me.uk/pontins/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/new-posts.png">
</div>
<div id="name" style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; text-align: center;">
  <p style="display: inline-block; font-family: 'Amatic SC'; color: #333; text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #3a3c3d; margin: 0; padding: 10px; font-size: 38px; line-height: 38px;">Brean Sands</p>
  <p>A description</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Maximillian, 

Thats great, is this possible to add a background 100% with some content over the image and Brean Sands text?

Comment: @StuartG94 What do you mean by a background 100%?

Comment: For example, if I keep it exactly as it is now, but on hover a white background would slide over the top of the image and name and have some text, a brief description about the new feature on the park, if that makes sense?

Comment: @StuartG94 I edited my answer to be like you described, at least as far as I know! Let me know if you need any more help!